# How to connect Mysql server via Flask use Python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, flask

I have trouble to connect mysql server  via Flask.
I have 4 files: server.py ,testDB.py,testDB2.py and *init*.py

First , if init.py import testDB.py and I run python server.py, it will print

```
changes in the database
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My user_info table will have user1.

However ,if init.py import testDB2.py and I run python server.py,it just print

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My user_info table will not appear user2.

How do I solve this problem ?
The difference between testDb.py and testDB2.py is I defined a function in testDB2.py

*init*.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import testDB
```

server.py

```
from Sw import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 8000
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    app.run(host = host, port = port)
```

testDB.py

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="1234",db="testdb")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql="""INSERT INTO user_info (user_id, user_email, user_password) VALUES ('user1','00000','000000')"""
    try:
       # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql)
       # Commit your changes in the database
        print "changes in the database"
        db.commit()
    except:
       # Rollback in case there is any error
        print "there is any error"
        db.rollback()
    db.close()
```

testDB2.py

```
  import MySQLdb
  def testDB():
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="1234",db="testdb")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql="""INSERT INTO user_info (user_id, user_email, user_password) VALUES ('user2','00000','000000')"""
        try:
           # Execute the SQL command
            cursor.execute(sql)
           # Commit your changes in the database
            print "changes in the database"
            db.commit()
        except:
           # Rollback in case there is any error
            print "there is any error"
            db.rollback()
        db.close()
```

Comment: You need to call the `testDB` function in `testDB2.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @dirn said in the comment, the reason the database isn't updated in the second case is because you've defined a function, but then never made use of it.  Just as any other function in Python, it waits for another line of code to call it into action.  When you import it into your `init.py` file, you have two ways of running it.  You can modify `init.py` like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import testDB2
testDB2.testDB()
```

Which then runs your function from the `init.py` file, or you can modify `testDB2.py` and run the function from there, just by adding `testDB()` to the end of that file (outside the function, of course).